# How to list members of superusergroup in hadoop?

Tags: hdfs

"hdfs" is the name of the superusergroup as per dfs.permissions.superusergroup in our cluster. But, i am not sure how to see all the members in the the superusergroup. getting names from  the file /etc/group is not working. I was asked to find for the namenode. but how to check it for namenode?
please let me know your suggestion.

Thanks,
Jee

Comment: How (Why) getting name from `/etc/group` is not working?

Comment: I extracted the members from the /etc/group file for a given group. But i was told that, the file is for current server, but not for hdfs NameNode. NameNode will have users and groups , which is different from the file /etc/group.

Comment: Run the same command on the server where the `namenode` daemon is running.

Comment: Hi franklinsijo, Thanks for your reply. I don't have access to the namenode. I came to know that as a normal user, I can not able to list all the members of superusergroup from namenode. But, I can check if a particular user in the group or not by running the commang hdfs groups <username>.  So, my issue has been solved. Once again, Thanks to everyone.